# What does $\left[\pi \cdot \frac{2}{1} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{6}{5} \ldots \ldots \infty\right]$ equals?

Tags: pi, infinite-product

I recently came across this interesting question

Find the value of $\left[\pi(\frac{2}{1}) (\frac{2}{3} )(\frac{4}{3}) (\frac{4}{5}) (\frac{6}{5})(\frac{6}{7})(\frac{8}{7})(\frac{8}{9}) \cdots (\infty)\right]$

**My Approach:** I could see a pattern forming like $$\left[2\pi\ \cdot \left(1 - \frac{1}{3}\right) \cdot \left(1 + \frac{1}{3}\right) \cdot \left(1 - \frac{1}{5}\right) \cdot \left(1 + \frac{1}{5}\right) \ldots \ldots \infty \right]$$

But not able to see how to proceed further

Comment: I'm not sure what the tags should be since I am a little uncertain as to in which domain it lies. However my question source mentions that it is an integral question

Comment: It's the Wallis product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Comment: This is essentially the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product). As it stands, the integral context is not present. But it is well-known, e.g., it's central to the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's $\pi$ times the WP, so is $\pi^2/2$.